# Shopify - Does Liquid Process Before JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to call shopify asset urls using javascript, dynamically concatenating a string into the liquid code, but it throws an error.  I think that the Liquid must be processing before the JS.

```
function loadProductThumbnails(size) {
  $(".hammock-thumbnail1 img").attr("src", "{{ \'"+size+"-side-main-image.png' | asset_img_url: '150x150' }}");
}
```

Is this possible?  I'm working with over a thousand images and had to type each liquid image url to generate separately.  If I could do this dynamically, I cut the code down quite a bit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquid is rendered server side so you cannot integrate a JS var into your Liquid string.

You might make something like capturing part of your Liquid var with {% capture %} then use it in your function as var.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'm going to have to this some thought.  All image URLs are generated through liquid tags, so I would definitely have to figure out how to dynamically create them through liquid using logic and string filters if it's possible.  However, I believe with Shopify you're unable to use Liquid logic in .js.liquid and .css.liquid files, so maybe it can be done with a cleverly designed normal .liquid file using some logic like you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function loadProductThumbnails(size) {
   $(".hammock-thumbnail1 img").attr("src", ""+size+"-side-main-image.png");
 }



 the `src` attribute maybe is not correct?
```

Comment: The "src" attribute is correct, based on the HTML syntax `<img src="smiley.gif" />`